# CClientScript::POS_READY prevent external script running yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm using registerScriptFile in the my view

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/comment.js', 
    CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

and when I click on the button which has a click function related, it does do anything. I check the html code, the script is not included in the page.

I dont understand why ?

Can you give me some idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you give any errors in firebug?

Comment: Yes,  and nothing is displayed in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue (But I didn't actually have the comment.js file so that why, as it says POS_READY inserts it into the JQuery ready function), but this worked for me with:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/comment.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

Comment: When I use POS_END, I get an syntax error. It does not recognize the <?php  .  in my js script. I run my js.script within the script tag and there is no error.  Why?   @Jonnny

Comment: Have you tried just running comment.js code in the HTML. just manually add it to your view and see what it says and what's in the console

Comment: Yes , when I put my script in Html , it works @Jonnny

Comment: So have you tried `POS_HEAD` rather than `POS_READY` @klark - updated answer to reflect this also as this works on my system

Answer (score 0):

The script is not included in the page because the value `CClientScript::POS_READY` is not valid for the `registerScriptFile()` method (see documentation). You can put your javascript code inside `$(document).ready` function in the comment.js file.